# Segment text from bad lightining images using python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, text-segmentation

I have three types of images and want to segment text from them. So I get a clean binarized img like the first image below. The three types of images are below

I've tried various techniques but it always have some cases to fail. I tried first to threshold the img using `otsu` algorithm but it gave bad results in images below

I tried `Guassian`, `bilateral` and normal blur kernel but didn't enhance the results too much

Any one can provide help!

Code as the best I got results from

```
import cv2

gray = cv2.imread("/home/shrouk/Pictures/f2.png", 0)
thresholded = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv2.imshow("img", thresholded)
```

This is the final result I need 
 [image]

This the first type of images that fail. It fails because the text grey level it lighter in the right of the image

[image]

The result of otsu on it is here, I just need a way to enhance the words in the third line from right:

[image]

Second type that fails because the darker background

[image]

otsu result is not very good as the words to the left look like dilated words

[image]

This is the type that correctly thresholded by otsu as there is no noise

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`cv2.adaptiveThreshold()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html#adaptive-thresholding)

[image]
[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("2.png", 0)
adaptive = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,5)
cv2.imshow("adaptive", adaptive)
cv2.waitKey()
```